# Make a variable containing all digits from the stdout of the command run directly before it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a bash shell script that launches some jobs on a queuing system. After a job is launched, the launch command prints the job-id to the stdout, which I would like to 'trap' and then use in the next command. The job-id digits are the only digits in the stdout message.

```
#!/bin/bash
./some_function
>>> this is some stdout text and the job number is 1234...
```

and then I would like to get to:

```
echo $job_id
>>> 1234
```

My current method is using a tee command to pipe the original command's stdout to a `tmp.txt` file and then making the variable by grepping that file with a regex filter...something like:

```
echo 'pretend this is some dummy output from a function 1234' 2>&1 | tee tmp.txt
job_id=`cat tmp.txt | grep -o '[0-9]'`
echo $job_id

>>> pretend this is some dummy output from a function 1234
>>> 1 2 3 4
```

...but I get the feeling this is not really the most elegant or 'standard' way of doing this. What is the better way to do this?

And for bonus points, how do I remove the spaces from the grep+regex output?

Comment: Why piping to text file when you can pipe it directly to grep? Also, if the output has a fixed number of columns you don't need grep.

Comment: As a side comment, `job_id=$(cat tmp.txt | grep -o '[0-9])` can be reduced to `job_id=$(grep -o '[0-9]' tmp.txt)`. Regarding the question itself, it is difficult to know. You can also make the function itself return a value and use it later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -o` when you call your script:

```
jobid=$(echo 'pretend this is some dummy output from a function 1234' 2>&1 | 
    tee tmp.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$')

echo "$jobid"
1234
```

Comment: I think the `tee` part can be skipped as it was simply a means of later obtaining the number from a file. Otherwise, I would say this is the right approach.

Comment: Yes if output isn't needed in a file then command can be shortened to `jobid=$(echo 'pretend this is some dummy output from a function 1234' 2>&1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$')`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$ JOBID=`./some_function | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*/\1/'`
$ echo $JOBID
1234
```

Comment: It gets you the right output but you should really use `grep -o` when all you want to do is extract a pattern.